# How to access to specified folder via SSH/SFTP?

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, sshd, apache-virtualhost

I want that each user access to only their specific home directory via SFTP connection.

**Example structure:**

```
admin1 access to: /var/www/vhosts/vhost1
(optional)editor1 access to: /var/www/vhosts/vhost1/public

admin2 access to: /var/www/vhosts/vhost2
(optional)editor2 access to: /var/www/vhosts/vhost2/public

etc...
...`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're referring to a **Jail**, a folder where a specific user will be confined.
I will try to resume an *example of configuration*:

1) **Environment Preparation**
You need to do some steps to prepare Jail environment. We have to respect some security limitations imposed by SSH (if you want, you can disable them, byt it's really a bad idea!).

- *Jail* folder must be root-owned
- *Jail* fodler cannot be group/others writable
- `.ssh/` folder must have modes 700
- `authorized_keys` file must have modes 600

Let's assume you have a user whose username is `echoes` and whose home directory is `/home/echoes/` and let's assume we want to confine it into its own home directory.
Let's assume, as you say, we want to use an SFTP account with public-key authorization mechanism for it.

```
mkdir /home/echoes/.ssh
# write echoes public-key into /home/echoes/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown root /home/echoes/  
chmod 755 /home/echoes/  
chown -R echoes:echoes /home/echoes/.ssh/  
chmod 700 /home/echoes/.ssh/  
chmod 600 /home/echoes/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

2) **SSH Configuration**
Now we need to *match* the user and confine it into its own home directory. So, let's open SSH Server configuration file:

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Enable the `internal-sftp` to manage sftp connections:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Copy-Paste following lines into `sshd_config` configuration file. We are saying: when you match `echoes`, just move it into the folder defined by `ChrootDirectory` (its onw home folder in this example).

```
Match user echoes  
    ChrootDirectory /home/echoes/ 
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

3) **Allowing writing operations inside a sub-folder**
As you can see, the *home folder* of user is now root-owned, so `echoes` will not be able to write some files into it. For that reason, you can create a new sub-folder (i.e. `echoes-write`) allowing user to write inside it:

```
mkdir /home/echoes/echoes-write/
chown echoes:echoes /home/echoes/echoes-write/
chmod ug+w /home/echoes/echoes-write/
```

4) **Move automatically into its own writable folder**

If you need to automatically:
Match user -> Move it into a Jail -> Move it automatically into its writable sub-folder of its own Jail, let me know and I will try to resume that scenario as configuration steps.
As you didn't write info about your system, I have made lots of assumptions.